# Identifying Triangles using Flow Chart

Tags: algorithm, flowchart

Our professor asked us to create an algorithm using flowchart, the program will ask for the following input, either 2 sides and 1 angle, or 2 angles and 1 side, after getting the input, the program will identify the following, The type of triangle (ex. Scalene, Equilateral, Right, etc.) or if the triangle doesn't exist.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty good link, it should have all the information you need to do your assignment.
https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-triangles.html

In general, what you're trying to do is solve the triangle, and then use the triangles angles to figure out what kind of triangle it is.